# Please correct the grammar

Tags: grammar

Happy Father's Day! Thank you for everything! You're not only a good husband to me but a great father to our two girls. Thank you for loving us unconditionally. You've done so much and we do appreciate with gratitude all your efforts. You'd come up against pains and sacrifices yet you endured them with your greatest fortitude. What we are now is because of our prayers, your patience and perseverance.
I do not know my grammar is correct or not?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid that proofreading is explicitly off-topic here (but it looks fine, except "come up against")

Comment: Ok.It is important for me.I need to correct it someone.I want to learn something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy Father's Day! Thank you for everything! You're not only a good husband to me, but a great father to our two girls. Thank you for loving us unconditionally. You've done so much  - we so appreciate everything you do for us. You've taken pains and made sacrifices, yet you endured them with the utmost fortitude. It is your prayers, your patience and perseverance that have made us what we are.